# The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST. in Laravel 7.24.0

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I am trying to submit form data using Ajax, but I am getting the error message. I am unable to find the error.

Little heads up- I am using Sweet Alert to display success or error message

Here is the Controller Code -

```
class NewUserRegnController extends Controller
{
    public function submitNewRegn(Request $request){
     
        $first_name         =   $request->first_name;
        $last_name          =   $request->last_name;
        $email              =   $request->email;
        $password           =   Hash::make($request->password, [
                                     'memory' => '1024',
                                     'time' =>  '2',
                                     'threar' =>  '2',
                                    ]);
        // $confirm_password    =   $request->confirm_password;
        $mobno              =   $request->mobno;
        $dob                =   $request->dob;
        $gender             =   $request->gender;
        $address            =   $request->address;
        $country            =   $request->country;
        date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Kolkata"); 
        $time               =   date("Y-m-d,H:i:s ");   

        // $users = new Newuser();

        // $users->first_name = $first_name; 
        // $users->last_name = $last_name; 
        // $users->email = $email; 
        // $users->password = $password; 
        // $users->mobno = $mobno; 
        // $users->dob = $dob; 
        // $users->gender = $gender; 
        // $users->address = $address; 
        // $users->country = $country; 
        // $users->TIME_STAMP = $time; 

        // $users->save();
        $act =  "INSERT";
        DB::select('CALL my_stored_procedures(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)', array($act,0,$first_name,$last_name,$email,$password,$mobno,$dob,$gender,$address,$country,$time));
```

and the Blade-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">


    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B4gt1jrGC7Jh4AgTPSdUtOBvfO8shuf57BaghqFfPlYxofvL8/KUEfYiJOMMV+rV" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <!-- Ajax script -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.js"></script>


    <!-- Sweet Alert -->
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.min.js"></script>


    </head>
  <body>
    <!-- Navigation Bar --> 
   <div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-dark navbar-dark navbar-fixed-top">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="index">User Info</a>
  <ul class="navbar-nav">
    <li class="nav-item active">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">About Us</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact Us</a>
    </li>

    
  </ul>
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right ">
  <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="new_user"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Sign Up</a></li>
      <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="login"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a></li>
    </ul>

  
</nav>
    </div>
  </div>

 <div class="text-center pt-3">
<p style="color:red">For safety,Do Not hit the back button or refresh the page</p>
<p style="color:red">Use the buttons given in the form below</p>
</div>

<form class="form-group" id="new_user_form" method="post"  onsubmit="sendForm()" autocomplete="off">
 <div class="row  m-5 p-5 bg-warning text-white">
     <div class="col">
<div class="form-group">
  @csrf
 <label for="fname">First Name:</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="first_name" value="{{$first_name}}" readonly >
</div>
<div class="form-group">
 <label for="lname">Last Name:</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="last_name" value="{{$last_name}}" readonly>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
 <label for="email">Email/Username:</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email" value="{{$email}}" readonly>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="pwd">Password:</label>
  <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password"  value="{{$password}}" readonly>
</div>

  <div class="form-group">
 <label for="mobno">Mobile Number:</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="mobno" value="{{$mobno}}" readonly>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
 <label for="dob">Date of Birth(in YYYY-MM-DD):</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="dob" value="{{$dob}}" readonly>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <label for="gender">Gender:</label>
   <input type="text" class="form-control" name="gender" value="{{$gender}}" readonly>

 </div>
  <div class="form-group">
  <label for="address">Address:</label>
  <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" name="address"  readonly>{{$address}}</textarea>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
<label for="country">Country:</label>
 <input name="country" class="form-control" id="countrylist" value="{{$country}}" readonly>
</div>

 <div class="form-group">
 <label for="dt">Date and Time of Submission:</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="dt" value=@php date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Kolkata"); echo date("Y-m-d,H:i:s ") @endphp readonly>
</div>
<div class="form-group text-center">
<!-- <a href="{{url('recheck_form')}}"/><button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mb-2 text-center" onclick="store_using_ajax()">Submit</button> -->
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mb-2 text-center" id="submit_form">
</div>
<div class="form-group text-center ">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger"><a href="new_user">Cancel</a></button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-warning "><a href="">Edit</a></button>
</div>

</div>

</div>



</div>   
 


<script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
     $('#new_user_form').on('submit',function sendForm(e){
       e.preventDefault();
     var fd = new FormData(myform );
      var form_data = $(this);
    
     $.ajax({
       type:'POST',
       url: "submit-form" ,
       cache: false,
       processData: false,
         contentType: false,
       data:fd,

        data: $('#new_user_form').serialize(),

       success:function(response){
            swal({
         title: "Form Submitted Successfully!",
         text: "New User Registered !",
         icon: "success",
         button: "Okay",
       })

       },
       error: function(response){
       swal({
             title: "Error in submitting form",
             text: "Please refresh the page and try again! ",
             icon: "warning",
            button: "Okay",
            });
            
             }
  });

   });
     });

 </script>
```

The Routes -

```
Route::get('login','LoginController@loginuser');
Route::post('loggedinuser' , 'LoginController@loginvalidator' );
    


Route::get('new_user','NewUserController@getCountry');

Route::post('recheck-form', 'NewUserController@showdata');
Route::get('loginbackup',function(){
    return view('login-backup');

});


Route::post('submit-form' , 'NewUserRegnController@submitNewRegn');
```

I tried changing the controller and function names,but that didnt help. Also,deleting cookies and clearing browser history do not work either.

Comment: Can you share your routes from `web.php` for that controller?

Comment: `$('#new_user_form').on('submit',function(e))`? There's no function body

Comment: @mare96 I had forgotten. Now it's updated

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I missed that while copying the code

Comment: Try after clearing the cache for routes.

Comment: @VijaySankhat How to do that?

Comment: @Asish https://tecadmin.net/clear-cache-laravel-5/

Comment: @Asish
php artisan route:clear fire this command

Comment: Try changing _url: "submit-form"_ , to **url: "/submit-form" ,** ... It looks like submit url is at fault here.

Comment: @VijaySankhat It didn't solve the issue.

Comment: @VijaySankhat No

Comment: @SumanB Nope. Didnt work

Comment: You seem to have a couple of issues in your JS. In your Ajax call, you close the success callback with `};,` when it should be `},` (without the semi colon). That should throw a syntax error. Then after the error  callback, you have `e.preventDefault()`. That should be the first call in the callback for the click event, not in the settings object for your Ajax call.

Comment: could you please re-write that part of the code? @MagnusEriksson

Comment: I just told you those typos. Try fixing them and see if it makes any difference. And also, is the posted code **exactly** like the original, or have you made more copy/paste issues? You also mention that you get an error, but you never said _what_ error you're getting and where so I have no idea if those typos are the only issues.

Comment: I noticed and added a few missing html tags, and now the error message has disappeared. But, now, I cannot submit the form. On clicking the Submit button, nothing happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I forgot to add some closing html tags. Once that was done, I needed to add the CSRF tokens in the ajax script as well as meta tag.
*I re-edited the question with all the previously made mistakes to show where I did wrong.*

Here are the codes to be added :-

**Closing HTML Tags**

`</form>` `</body>`  `</html>`

**Meta tag**

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

**Ajax Request Header setup in the Ajax Script**

```
   $.ajaxSetup({
      headers: {
          'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
      }
  });
```

Comment: I could rectify the code, but now, after submitting, I am getting a new error message                  "SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'first_name' cannot be null